# How to disable sni on nginx?

Tags: nginx, https, sni

If I use the "--with-http_ssl_module" to buld nginx, it will always support sni and some old clients on windows xp will fail to connect.
How could i disable the use of sni on nginx?

Comment: Hi and welcome! How did you come around to this conclusion? Any hard evidences of this? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

SNI is an extension to TLS. This means that clients that don't support it will fall back to using the default mechanism. So no need to disable anything. If something works not as expected, it's simply because you haven't set a non-SNI configuration correctly.

In other words, an old non-SNI client is being presented with an invalid certificate.
To solve this, ensure that your default NGINX `server` block has the right TLS certificate.